# What is causing Cannot call method "getRange" of null

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm attempting to split data in a sheet (MASTERS) by the data in column E.
The data is a number.
I have the destination sheets set up in the same workbook which are named correctly, (eg. 3, 4, 5 etc) but every time I run I am getting the error

> TypeError: Cannot call method "getRange" of null. (line 12, file "02. split by column E"

```
var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var master = ss.getSheetByName('MASTER');
var colWidth = master.getMaxColumns();    

function copyRowsOnCondition() {
  var data = master.getDataRange().getValues();
  for(n=0;n<data.length;++n){
    if(data[n][4].length<16){ 
    Logger.log(data[n][4])
     var dest = ss.getSheetByName(data[n][4].toString().replace(/ /g,''));
     var destRange = dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1);
     master.getRange(n+1,1,1,colWidth).copyTo(destRange); 
     }
  }// loop
}
```

Comment: What is the `dest` sheet name? You are logging `data[n][4]` but setting the `dest` as `data[n][4].toString().replace(/ /g,'')`  so you may be seeing a value  in the log that is different than the value you are actually trying to get which would cause an error. The error is saying that your sheet by that name does not exist

Comment: the names of the destination sheets are numbers - eg from 1 to 10, which correlate to the runs of data in column E of the master sheet. I've checked that data in column 4 is plain text but it does seem as though it's reading the values differently. Strangely I've lifted this script from another worksheet (with a different column layout) were it was working fine.

Comment: what is the code at line `12`? and double check that there is a sheet named `MASTER`. the error has to do with there not being a sheet object to call `getRange` on

Comment: this is the offending line:  var destRange = dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1);

Comment: there is definitely a sheet named MASTER. Thanks.

Comment: The other sheet names that `dest` is the variable for, do not exist. Post a subset of the data in column `E` and the actual name or a screen shot of the sheet names. The error is because the two values, `col E` data and the `sheet names`,  are not matching up

Comment: I don['t know if you'd be able to follow this: https://docs.google.com/document/d/10-gDqXXS50urocpQtSHNbavxj2gOfZDnOJeOqal_B5Q/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: the data in column E definitely matches the sheet names. I've tried changing them to letters/names etc. but still same problem. Driving me mad. Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

In at least 1 case, no sheet is named whatever this returns: `data[n][4].toString().replace(/ /g,'')`

After line 9 (after your `Logger.log(data[n][4])`), you could remove everything and write:

```
var str = data[n][4].toString().replace(/ /g,'');
var dest = ss.getSheetByName(str)
if (dest) {
  Logger.log(str + " is an actual sheet's name");
  var destRange = dest.getRange(dest.getLastRow()+1,1);
  master.getRange(n+1,1,1,colWidth).copyTo(destRange); 
} else { 
  Logger.log(str + " is not an actual sheet's name.")
}
}// loop
}
```

The logs should now be helpful to find out what is wrong.

Comment: tried this, thanks, but nothing happened. No error, but no split data either.

Comment: I don't actually know how to do that. I should have explained I'm a complete novice. Apologies if I'm wasting your time. Thanks.

Comment: First run your function, then in the Script page click View > Logs. Let me know if the logs make any sense :)

Comment: that just brought up a time stamp.